# Angularjs - unable to push children items dynamically

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a simple nested json embedded in my html file to which I want to insert some data dynamically using form.

I am able to insert data to parent level but unable to insert to child level. What I am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <label>Enter Data</label>
        <input ng-model="name" type="text">
        <input ng-model="rollno" type="number">
        <input ng-model="id" type="text">
        <button ng-click="addData(data)">Enter Data</button>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Sr No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Roll No</th>
                <th>Subjects</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in myData">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.rollno}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="subject in data.subjects">{{subject.id1}}, {{subject.id2}}</td>
                <td><a href="" ng-click="removeData($index)">remove</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
            app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
                $scope.myData =[{"name":"Jon","rollno":123,"subjects":[{"id1":"Maths","id2":"Hindi"}]},{"name":"Ron","rollno":234,"subjects":[{"id1":"English","id2":"Hindi"}]}];
                $scope.addData = function(data){
                    $scope.myData.push({name:$scope.name,rollno:$scope.rollno,id1:$scope.id1}); 
                }
                $scope.removeData = function(index){
                    $scope.myData.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by parent and child level? Are you talking about JSON data? Please give an example of how you like to have?

Comment: I have this data with me - {"name":"Jon","rollno":123,"subjects":[{"id1":"Maths","id2":"Hindi"}]},{"name":"Ron","rollno":234,"subjects":[{"id1":"English","id2":"Hindi"}]}. Now I want to add one more row using Name as Sharon, RollNo as 345, Id1 as History. But as Id1 & Id2 are in child level, I am unable to insert them into my table.

Comment: You did not show where the function addData was called, and 'data' was not used. However, if you want to insert 'subjects', you can do something like var newSubjects = [{id1: 'History', 'id1': 'English'}]; $scope.myData.push({name: 'newData', rollno:'newRollno', subjects:newSubjects });

Comment: Yes, it is called in html - <button ng-click="addData(data)">Enter Data</button>

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. Will you try $scope.myData.push({name:$scope.name,rollno:$scope.rollno,subject:[{id1:$scope.id1}]);

Comment: I have one more question. There is this jsfiddle - fiddle.jshell.net/jonhartmann/xd7e5eha. How do I add dynamic child items to it using form? Suppose I have an texbox with button <input type="text" ng-model="child.name"> and on js, I have "name:$scope.name" in place of "name : 'Child ' + count". I want user to input child names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to insert subjects as well using addData function you can do the below. In html add those ng-models

```
    <input ng-model="name" type="text">
    <input ng-model="rollno" type="number">
    <input ng-model="id" type="text">
    <input ng-model="subid1" type="text"/>
    <input ng-model="subid2" type="text"/>
```

In js

```
         $scope.addData = function(data){
        var arrData = {name:$scope.name,rollno:$scope.rollno,subjects:[{id1:$scope.subid1,id2:$scope.subid2 }]};
        $scope.myData.push(arrData);
    }
```

Comment: I have one more question. There is this jsfiddle -  http://fiddle.jshell.net/jonhartmann/xd7e5eha/. How do I add dynamic child items to it using form? Suppose I have an texbox with button <input type="text" ng-model="child.name"> and on js, I have "name:$scope.name" in place of "name : 'Child ' + count". I want user input child names.

Comment: You can use ng-submit in form to submit it